# How to understand the grammar structure of this sentence? especially the "by which that which"part?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

"This whole government is carried on with our assistance and they try to keep us in ignorance of our power of cooperation between ourselves **by which that which** is in our own hands at present can be claimed by us and administered by us." I believe there are multiple clauses included and how to understand the two "which" ?